# Try to get a counter of compound pattern in xsl

Tags: xml, xslt

The structure of my style sheet is as following:

```
    <xsl:apply-templates select="pattern1|pattern2|pattern3"/>
        ...
    <xsl:template match="pattern1|pattern2|pattern3">
        <xsl:variable name="counter"> 
            <xsl:number/>
        </xsl:variable>
        ...
    </xsl:template>
```

The ***counter*** variable is reset for each pattern. I want to get a ***counter*** for all the matches.
How can I achieve it?
Thanks!

XML source structure as follow:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<root>
    <div class="entry">
        <div class="headword">
            ...
        </div>
        <div class="information-forms">
            test infomation block
        </div>
        <div class="definition">
            <div>text </div>
            <div>text </div>
                  ... ...
            <div>text </div>
        </div>
        <div class="example-sentences">
            <ol>
                <li>sentence here</li>
                <li>sentence here</li>
            ... ...
                <li>sentence here</li>
            </ol>
        </div>
        <div class="synonyms-reference">
            <div class="syn-para">
                Synonyms: ... ...
            </div>
            <div class="ant-para">
                Antonyms: ... ... 
            </div>
        <div class="...">
              ...
        </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="entry">
        ...
    </div>
    <div class="entry">
        ...
    </div>
    ... ... 
</root>
```

I want to get a counter of nodes of multiple patterns under each div[@class="entry"] node.

So the counter should be reset when starting in a new div[@class="entry"] node.
XPath of the patterns is

```
div[@class='information-forms']
|
div[@class='definition'].div
|
div[@class='example-sentences']/ol/li
```

I can figure out how to do it by parse it twice with xsl style sheet.( First time put all matching nodes in one node.) But It seems to me that it can be done in a single pass. I hope someone experienced in XSL/XSLT can help me. Thanks.

Comment: Please, give a complete example -- a complete (as small as possible) XML document, the exact wanted result and the rules that the transformation must implement. It isn't quite clear what value you want to have in the variable -- please, edit the question and show this explicitly -- otherwise people need to guess and the correctness of the answers would be random.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the following. Explanation: call a specific template for the set of nodes to be processed, supplying the set as a parameter, then use position() within the template.

```
<xsl:template match="div[@class='entry']">
    <div>
        <xsl:variable name="divs" select="
        div[@class='information-forms']
        |
        div[@class='definition']/div
        |
        div[@class='example-sentences']/ol/li
        "/>
        <xsl:call-template name="divs">
            <xsl:with-param name="divs" select="$divs"/>
        </xsl:call-template>
    </div>
</xsl:template>



<xsl:template name="divs">
    <xsl:param name="divs"/>
    <xsl:for-each select="$divs">
        <pos><xsl:value-of select="position()"/></pos>
    </xsl:for-each>
</xsl:template>
```

With the XML input you supplied, this gives as result

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<out>
    <div>
        <pos>1</pos>
        <pos>2</pos>
        <pos>3</pos>
        <pos>4</pos>
        <pos>5</pos>
        <pos>6</pos>
        <pos>7</pos>
    </div>
    <div/>
    <div/>
</out>
```

Answer (score 0):

**Use appropriately the `count` and `level` attributes of `xsl:number` like in the below transformation**:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
 xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
 <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>
 <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

 <xsl:template match="node()|@*">
     <xsl:copy>
       <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
     </xsl:copy>
 </xsl:template>

 <xsl:template match=
  "*[starts-with(name(), 'A') and contains(name(), '.')]
  |
   *[starts-with(name(), 'B') and contains(name(), '.')]
  |
   *[starts-with(name(), 'C') and contains(name(), '.')]
  ">
   <X oldname="{name()}">
    <xsl:number level="any" count=
  "*[starts-with(name(), 'A') and contains(name(), '.')]
  |
   *[starts-with(name(), 'B') and contains(name(), '.')]
  |
   *[starts-with(name(), 'C') and contains(name(), '.')]
  "/>
    <xsl:apply-templates/>
   </X>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**when this transformation is applied on the following XML document**:

```
<t>
    <A>
        <A.1>
            <A.1.1/>
            <A.1.2/>
        </A.1>
        <A.2>
            <A.2.1/>
        </A.2>
        <A.3/>
    </A>
    <B>
        <B.1/>
        <B.2>
            <B.2.1/>
            <B.2.2>
                <B.2.2.1/>
                <B.2.2.2/>
            </B.2.2>
        </B.2>
    </B>
    <C>
        <C.1/>
        <C.2>
            <C.2.1/>
            <C.2.2>
                <C.2.2.1/>
                <C.2.2.2/>
            </C.2.2>
        </C.2>
    </C>
</t>
```

**the wanted correct result (absolute numbering for all elements whose name contains `"."`) is produced**:

```
<t>
    <A>
        <X oldname="A.1">1
            <X oldname="A.1.1">2</X>
            <X oldname="A.1.2">3</X></X>
        <X oldname="A.2">4
            <X oldname="A.2.1">5</X></X>
        <X oldname="A.3">6</X>
    </A>
    <B>
        <X oldname="B.1">7</X>
        <X oldname="B.2">8
            <X oldname="B.2.1">9</X>
            <X oldname="B.2.2">10
                <X oldname="B.2.2.1">11</X>
                <X oldname="B.2.2.2">12</X></X></X>
    </B>
    <C>
        <X oldname="C.1">13</X>
        <X oldname="C.2">14
            <X oldname="C.2.1">15</X>
            <X oldname="C.2.2">16
                <X oldname="C.2.2.1">17</X>
                <X oldname="C.2.2.2">18</X></X></X>
    </C>
</t>
```

**Update**: The OP has noe provided a sample XML document and clarified that the numbering must be reset at each `div[@class='entry]`.

**Solution**:

This transformation:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
 xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
 <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>
 <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

 <xsl:template match="node()|@*" name="identity">
  <xsl:copy>
   <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
  </xsl:copy>
 </xsl:template>

 <xsl:template match=
  "div[@class='information-forms']
  |
   div[@class='definition']/div
  |
   div[@class='example-sentences']/ol/li
  ">
  <xsl:number level="any" 
  count="div[@class='information-forms']
              |
               div[@class='definition']/div
              |
               div[@class='example-sentences']/ol/li"
  from="div[@class='entry']"/>

  <xsl:call-template name="identity"/>
 </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**when applied on the the following XML document**:

```
<root>
    <div class="entry">
        <div class="headword">
                ...
        </div>
        <div class="information-forms">
                test infomation block
        </div>
        <div class="definition">
            <div>text </div>
            <div>text </div>
                      ... ...
            <div>text </div></div>
        <div class="example-sentences">
            <ol>
                <li>sentence here</li>
                <li>sentence here</li>
                ... ...
                <li>sentence here</li>
            </ol>
        </div>
        <div class="synonyms-reference">
            <div class="syn-para">
                    Synonyms: ... ...
            </div>
            <div class="ant-para">
                    Antonyms: ... ...
            </div>
            <div class="...">
                  ...
            </div></div></div>
    <div class="entry">
            ...
    </div>
    <div class="entry">
        <div class="headword">
                ...
        </div>
        <div class="information-forms">
                test infomation block
        </div>
        <div class="definition">
            <div>text </div>
            <div>text </div>
                      ... ...
            <div>text </div></div>
        <div class="example-sentences">
            <ol>
                <li>sentence here</li>
                <li>sentence here</li>
                ... ...
                <li>sentence here</li>
            </ol>
        </div>
        <div class="synonyms-reference">
            <div class="syn-para">
                    Synonyms: ... ...
            </div>
            <div class="ant-para">
                    Antonyms: ... ...
            </div>
            <div class="...">
                  ...
            </div></div></div>
</root>
```

**produces the wanted result** (the wanted elements are numbered and the numbers are reset at each `div[@class='entry]`):

```
<root>
   <div class="entry">
      <div class="headword">
                ...
        </div>1<div class="information-forms">
                test infomation block
        </div>
      <div class="definition">2<div>text </div>3<div>text </div>
                      ... ...
            4<div>text </div>
      </div>
      <div class="example-sentences">
         <ol>5<li>sentence here</li>6<li>sentence here</li>
                ... ...
                7<li>sentence here</li>
         </ol>
      </div>
      <div class="synonyms-reference">
         <div class="syn-para">
                    Synonyms: ... ...
            </div>
         <div class="ant-para">
                    Antonyms: ... ...
            </div>
         <div class="...">
                  ...
            </div>
      </div>
   </div>
   <div class="entry">
            ...
    </div>
   <div class="entry">
      <div class="headword">
                ...
        </div>1<div class="information-forms">
                test infomation block
        </div>
      <div class="definition">2<div>text </div>3<div>text </div>
                      ... ...
            4<div>text </div>
      </div>
      <div class="example-sentences">
         <ol>5<li>sentence here</li>6<li>sentence here</li>
                ... ...
                7<li>sentence here</li>
         </ol>
      </div>
      <div class="synonyms-reference">
         <div class="syn-para">
                    Synonyms: ... ...
            </div>
         <div class="ant-para">
                    Antonyms: ... ...
            </div>
         <div class="...">
                  ...
            </div>
      </div>
   </div>
</root>
```

**Explanation**: Appropriate use of the `from` attribute of `xsl:number`.

Comment: I need to reset the counter for each `div[@class="entry"]`. Help!

Comment: Still not clear what you want to obtain as result. Please, edit again and provide a minimal (but complete example). I have the feeling that your problem can be solved using another attribute of `xsl:number` -- just describe precisely what you need to get as result at what point in the code.

Comment: I have edited my question with more information. Hope this time I explained what I am trying to do.

Comment: @kohan:Yes. It is simpler and shorter than any other solution presented.

Answer (score 0):

Try using

```
count(preceding::pattern1|preceding::pattern2|preceding::pattern3)
```

To start the counter again at each `div[@class="entry"]` node, you can use

```
count(preceding::pattern1|preceding::pattern2|preceding::pattern3) - count(preceding::div[@class='entry'][1]/preceding::pattern1|preceding::div[@class='entry'][1]/preceding::pattern2|preceding::div[@class='entry'][1]/preceding::pattern3)‌​
```

Comment: This is not even syntactically valid!